# How do I speculatively receive requests from multiple MPI sending processes?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Say I have 4 MPI processes labelled: P0, P1, P2, P3. Each process potentially has packets to send to other processes, but may not.

I.e. P0 needs to send packets to P1 and P2, or

```
    P0->[P1, P2]
```

Similarly,

```
    P1->[P3] 
    P2 ->[]
    P3 -> [P1]
```

So P1 has to receive potential packets from both P0 and P3, and P3 has to receive packets from P1, and P2 from P0.

How do I do this in MPI? It's sort of like a 'sparse' all to all communication, however in order to set up the recvs I need to know at each process how many times it will receive packets, I'm not sure how to do this, as using MPI_MProbe in a loop breaks as soon as the receiver detects a single packet, how do I ensure that it only breaks when it receives all packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each process needs to tell every other process how many msgs there will be, including zero. You can do that with an all-to-all.

However, more efficiently you can do a reduce-scatter. Each process makes a send buffer of length P with 0/1 depending whether a msg is sent. View that as a matrix with element (i,j) is 1 if process `i` sends to `j`. Then a reduce-scatter basically gives each process `j` the sum of elements in column `j`. Meaning the number of messages it will receive. You then run a `MPI_Probe` that many times.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with the following similar method to you @Victor Eijkhout,

Code snippet in Rust:

```
let mut to_receive = vec![0i32; size as usize];

world.all_reduce_into(
            &packet_destinations,
            &mut to_receive,
            SystemOperation::sum(),
        );
```

Where `packet_destinations` is a vector containing 1 if the process corresponding to the index is being sent data from the current process, and zero otherwise.

Thank you for your response, I loved your HPC textbook by the way.

Comment: For completeness let me mention that my textbooks are now collected at https://theartofhpc.com/ Older versions can be found in many locations....

Comment: An allreduce is probably fine, but strictly speaking that gives each process also the information for other processes, which it doesn't need. A reduce-scatter is the most parsimonious. It obviates the need to create an output vector of length P.